# CGI Index yields 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I'm running nginx with php-cgi on an ubuntu computer.  Things seem to be working okay except for the major detail that visiting `/` yields "403 Forbidden" from nginx.  Visiting `/index.php` works just fine.  If I add `index.html` and go to `/` that works too.

```
server {
    root /home/ajcrites/projects/php/devays/public/;
    server_name sub.localhost;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

It would seem like `fastcgi_index index.php;` would cover this, but that is clearly not the case.  Is there something I need to add to get `/` to serve `/index.php`?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `index.php` to your index directive so that you have something like `index index.html index.php;`

See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html